# Quick question on astronomical units

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astronomy, astrophysics, luminosity, parallax

I'm trying to solve for $\frac{M*}{M_0}$ and $p''$ using these two equations:

Here is the lecturer's working, I worked it out several times and I got a different answer!

[image]

Surely when you use Kepler's third law, everything is in astronomical units (solar masses, yrs, arc seconds). So on the LHS of equation 3, it should be $\frac{M*}{M_0}$ instead, right?

Substituting into equation 3, I get:

$$3.71 + 10\log\left[\frac{1}{2T^2}\left(\frac{\theta}{p''}\right)^3\right] + 5 \log(p'') = 0 $$

$$p'' = 0.343$$

I'm not sure how the lecturer got a value of $0.086$?

Comment: You're off by [a factor of $4\pi^2$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/112541/44126).

Comment: in the keppler's third law equation? I thought in astronomical units, all pre-factors are assumed to be = 1?

Answer (score 1):

The full statement of [Kepler's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion), in modern notation, is
$$
G\frac{M_1+M_2}{4\pi^2} = \frac{r^3}{T^2}.
$$
From our solar system we learn that $$G = 4\pi^2 \mathrm{\frac{AU^3}{year^2\mathit M_\odot}}$$ since it takes us a year to orbit the sun at one AU. So your statement that "all the prefactors are 1" is not quite correct.

I fat-fingered in my initial comment, though: $0.34/4\pi^2 = 0.0086$ is still a factor of ten away from your lecturer's answer. It's possible that this is a red herring, or that there is more than one mistake here.

Comment: As shown above, kepler's 3rd law in astronomical units give $G = 4\pi^2$, which makes all prefactors = 1

Answer (score 1):

$$ 3.71 + 10\log\left[\frac{1}{2T^2}\left(\frac{\theta}{p''}\right)^3\right] + 5 \log(p'') = 0 $$

Using T = 171 yr, $\theta = 3.75$ as before, I realized I made an absolute amateur mistake! I used log base $e$ i.e.$\ln$ instead of base 10 $log_{10}$!

That solved it. My answers matched the provided solutions.

Comment: I love a story with a happy ending!