# How can I change our units so that Newton's gravitational constant is $G=1$?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, unit-conversion, absolute-units

I'm just wondering if you can change our arbitrary values for , say, the kg, meter, or newton so that G=1 instead of 6.67x10^-11

Comment: its just a matter of re-scaling.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/112541/44126

Answer (score 5):

This is commonly done in general relativity to avoid cluttering up already complicated equations with factors of $G$ and $c$. The system of units is called [geometrised units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system). The [table here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system#Geometrical_quantities) gives the units for the various physical quantities in these units.

Answer (score 1):

Atomic units (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_units) are used for a similar purpose for quantum mechanical calculations. In this system many quantities such as the reduced Planck's constant $ \hbar $ are equal to one. You can always make whatever units you want.

$$ G = 6.67408×10^{-11} m^3 kg^{-1}s^{-2} $$

So let's just make up some new unit of length called A, and let's say

$$ 1 A^3 = 6.67408×10^{-11} m^3 $$

Now in our new units:

$$ G = 1 A^3 kg^{-1} s^{-2} $$

Comment: While this makes the numerical value one, the OP I believe is asking to make $G=1$, in the sense of $G$ also being dimensionless, in which case John Rennie's answer is the more appropriate one.

Comment: thanks for the input, but actually I don't want a dimensionless value. I should have clarified a bit since I stated it wrong. I was wondering if you can change our units of mass so that G=1 m^3*kg^-1*s^-2 instead of the normal 6.67x10^-11.           Could you just divide our current definition of the Newton, 1kg=9.8N by 6.67x10^-11?          I apologize for the confusing context         - or is it not possible to redefine our units for force/mass so that G=1 (with proper units)

Comment: thanks iammax. Can you change it for the unit of mass or the unit of force instead? in other words, is there a unit of mass or force so that G=1? and what would the difference be between that and the normal unit for mass and force.   what would that value be?

Answer (score 1):

I mean, trivially, yes.  You can do whatever the hell you want.  Let's make a new unit of force called a "Gravinewton" (GN) such that:
$\frac{1 \text{ kg} \cdot 1 \text{ kg}}{(1 \text{ m})^2} \cdot 1 \frac{\text{ m}^3}{\text{kg}\cdot\text{s}^2} = 1 \text{ GN}$

Disclaimer: this will make Newton's second law into $\vec{F} = m\vec{a}\cdot6.67\times10^{-11}$, so, that's a thing.

Answer (score -3):

If we take G=1, then masses should be in solar mass and and distances in parsec and time in year.

Comment: Where does solar masses and come int to it?

Comment: Technically this *is* an answer. However, while it's [on the right track](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/112541/44126), the details are wrong.