# What is gravitational constant in this context?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, terminology, soft-question, notation, physical-constants

I've been reading an article and it gives me the following formula:

> $\vec{v}_B(t) = \vec{v}_0 - \mu_sgt \hat u_0$

It governs the velocity of a ball. In its explanation, it says:

> The gravitational constant is represented by $g$.

Which "gravitational constant" is being referred? I want to believe it is referring to [gravity on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth) $9.8$ m/s², that would make sense in the equation (since the $\mu_s$ stands for friction coefficient and is a small value). There is the [gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant) which is $6.67408 \times 10^{-11} \rm \; m^3 \; kg^{-1} \; s^{-2}$, but it is so small that it seems senseless to use in this equation and I've read it is commonly used as $G$ (and not $g$).

What gravitational constant is it referring to? I've searched through this article and other related ones, all of them use but don't specify.

Comment: Have you tried to see how they arrived at the formula? Do you think the dimensions would work out with both of them? :)

Comment: What you mean with "how they arrived the formula"? I came here to ask exactly because I think the constant $6.67408 \times 10^{-11} ...$ is strange and doesn't seem to fit the formula, but it is also called gravitational constant.

Comment: I meant could you figure out how they derived the formula?

Comment: It doesn't state the derivation process, just says "From Newton’s Laws of motion".

Comment: Hint: what units does $g$ need to have for that equation to be valid? The left side is a velocity vector, so the right side must also be a velocity vector.

Comment: Which article? Which page?

Comment: [This article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2900/db5a2356897694337151424dd951d8e89828.pdf?_ga=2.163694909.306525322.1590594361-322585157.1590004580), page 217.

Comment: It should be obvious from context. What is the usual trajectory for a ball? I have never seen g or G used in anything other than the conventional ways, which you already describe in your questions.

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question, use dimensional analysis. You can't add or subtract terms with different units.  Two terms are velocities, so the final term $\mu g t \hat u$ must also have velocity units, like meters per second.  It's probably the case that $\mu$ is a friction coefficient, which is a dimensionless ratio between two forces, and $\hat u$ is a dimensionless unit vector.  Since $g$ and $G$ have different units, only one of them fits here.

Don't get too hung up on whether a number is "big" or "small."  In the right units, [even $G$ has a "nice" value](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/112541/44126).